# "Die Bächlein" instead of expected "das Bächlein"

Tags: gender, diminutive

A line from *Die schöne Müllerin* reads

> bis das Meer will trinken die Bächlein aus.

I always had trouble with genders, but I did understand a *-lein* suffix to make its root neuter, unconditionally.
So how can it be ***die** Bächlein*?

Comment: Same with *-chen*.

Comment: One may assume that it might be plural as there is not only one Bächlein flowing towards the sea. All Bäche flow into rivers and all rivers flow into the sea.

Answer (score 25):

The singular form is **das Bächlein** and, as you correctly state, this is a neuter diminutive that ends in *-lein*; **die Bächlein** is the plural form. For completeness, here is the declension table for the noun *Bächlein*:

```
       Singular:           Plural:
Nom.: das Bächlein      die Bächlein
Gen.: des Bächleins     der Bächlein
Dat.: dem Bächlein      den Bächlein
Akk.: das Bächlein      die Bächlein
```

In the verse

> bis das Meer will trinken *die Bächlein* aus

the form *die Bächlein* is neuter, plural, accusative.

Comment: Thanks, I never thought of the plural; in the series of poems, there is ONE "Bach" that is actually a character in the narrative, and that's what misled me. The last poem of the series, in which this line appears, has a much larger perspective, in which the main "Bach" could reasonably be seen as a part of the larger cosmos, with its brother and sister "Bachlein".